# Miscrosoft GraphAPI /v1.0/me. "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation"

Tags: authentication, microsoft-graph-api, access-token

I want to get my information using MS Graph API /v1.0/me.
When I try to call MS Graph API /v1.0/me with this access token, an error message "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" is shown.

I have already gotten access token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX/oauth2/v2.0/authorize using ClientID, which is registered in Azure AD and Scope "openid".

On Azure side the Permissions given to this Client is below, I think it is enough.

[image: Permissions]

Please tell me how can I solve it.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the request id and timestamp from the error message Graph API returned?
Also describe the flow used to get the access token - Which Entra Authentication flow are you using?
You may also want to paste the token in https://jwt.ms and share the value `scp` claim.